# Controlling phone and making calls remotely

Tags: remote-control, ssh, remote-access, voip

I'm wondering if there's a way to connect to my phone via, say, ssh and be able to make calls and send texts remotely.

Use case would be for when I'm abroad but have internet, I'd be able to contact people without roaming and whatnot.

Comment: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Connections-From-Mobile-to-Mobile-Devices/ta-p/280

Comment: If you have internet, why not using a SIP solution? Plenty of them available, usually providing calls and texts. And for the latter, there're also messengers. No need to remotely access a home device for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Teamviewer](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Connections-From-Mobile-to-Mobile-Devices/ta-p/280) app for remote control